# extract only specific file types from zip with php

Tags: php, file, types, unzip

I'm creating a simple webapp my students can use to upload their projects (as a .zip file) to my server. This app takes the .zip > unzips it > displays a link to their web-project.

I'm using a php function like this, to extract the zip file:

```
function openZip($file_to_open) {  
    global $target;  

    $zip = new ZipArchive();  
    $x = $zip->open($file_to_open);  
    if($x === true) {  
        $zip->extractTo($target);  
        $zip->close();  

        unlink($file_to_open);  
    } else {  
         die("There was a problem. Please try again!"); 
    } 
}
```

is it possible to check the type of the files being extracted and only allow specific file types to get unzipped? Not that I don't trust my students... just want to make sure nothing malicious makes its way to my server.

my students will be uploading simple web projects, so I only want to allow .html, .css and .js (as well as image file types, and directories) to be extracted.

Comment: Maybe [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11387993/php-ziparchive-unzip-only-certain-extensions) can be useful.

Answer (score 1):

Check out [ZipArchive::getFromName](http://php.net/manual/en/ziparchive.getfromname.php) to pull just 1 file from the Zip by filename. You may also want to take a look at [ZipArchive::getFromIndex](http://php.net/manual/en/ziparchive.getfromindex.php)

```
$zip = new ZipArchive;
if ($zip->open('test1.zip') === TRUE)
{
    echo $zip->getFromName('testfromfile.php');
    $zip->close();
}
else
{
    echo 'failed';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can always try [finfo_file()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.finfo-file.php) like this:

```
$finfo = finfo_open(FILEINFO_MIME_TYPE);
echo finfo_file($finfo, "yourfile.zip");
finfo_close($finfo);
```