# How to extract only image file and delete rest of the file

Tags: php, zip, unzip

I'm trying to extract a zip file on my server and sometimes these files contain MAC_STORE and other formats that users should not put in a zip file.

Here is what I've tried

```
public static function extractItem($path, $ext_path) {
        $zip = new ZipArchive;

        $zip->open($path);
        $filename = array();

    for ($i = 0; $i < $zip->numFiles; $i++) {
        $stat = $zip->statIndex($i);
        if ($stat['size'] != 0) {
            $filename[] = basename($stat['name']);
        }
    }
  }
```

If the zip file contains .jpg,jpeg,png then it's okay and if it contains other formats i want to delete them

Here is the response of `$filename array`

```
Array
 (
   [0] => Screen Shot 2017-10-04 at 12.38.47 AM.png
   [1] => ._Screen Shot 2017-10-04 at 12.38.47 AM.png
   [2] => Screen Shot 2017-10-04 at 12.38.50 AM.png
   [3] => ._Screen Shot 2017-10-04 at 12.38.50 AM.png
 )
```

In the zip file there is only two images

Comment: What is the `PHP_EOL` doing in there? A file name is not a text file... And where do you check for the file name extension in your code?

Answer (score 0):

You could just only extract the files with a .jpg,jpeg,png extension, it is explained here :
[php zipArchive unzip only certain extensions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11387993/php-ziparchive-unzip-only-certain-extensions)

But you would replace the regex finder with this instead :

```
preg_match('#.+([jpg|jpeg|png])$#i', $entry)
```

Comment: I have two files in my zip file and the loop is running four times?