# detect images in zip upload and extracting

Tags: php, upload, zip

I have this script to upload a ZIP file and extract the images inside it in PHP. I found it on Youtube. It uploads the file and extracts it correctly but it's not able to detect the images. It extracts the files whether it contains images or something else.
For example, if I upload a ZIP file which contains MP3 files, it uploads it and extracts it.
Thanks in advance

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['btn_zip']))
{
    $upload_ok = '';
    if($_FILES['zip_file']['name'] != '')   
    {
        $file_name = $_FILES['zip_file']['name'];
        $array = explode(".",$file_name);
        $name = $array[0];
        $ext = $array[1];
        if($ext == 'zip')
        {
            $path = 'upload/';
            $location = $path . $file_name;
            if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['zip_file']['tmp_name'],$location))
            {
                $zip = new ZipArchive;
                if($zip->open($location))
                {
                    $zip->extractTo($path);
                    $zip->close();
                }
                $files = scandir($path . $name);
                foreach($files as $file)
                {
                    $file_ext = end(explode(".", $file));
                    $allowed_ext = array('jpg','png');
                    if(in_array($file_ext,$allowed_ext))
                    {
                        $new_name = $file;
                        $upload_ok = '1';
                        copy($path.$name.'/'.$file, $path . $new_name);
                        unlink($path.$name.'/'.$file);
                    }
                }
                unlink($location);
                rmdir($path.$name);
            }
        }
    }
    if($upload_ok=='1')
    {
        echo "Done";    
    }
    else 
    {
        echo "Failed";
    }
}
?>
<form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<input type="file" name="zip_file">
<input type="submit" name="btn_zip" value="Upload">
</form>
```

Comment: Already answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/11388048/1597430

Comment: Is it possible to make some changes in my code?

Comment: Is there anyone to help me?!